# Search favorite questions by tag

Tags: feature-request, support, bookmarks, search

Favorite questions on Stack Overflow I feel is highly unused feature of all the features provided on the site. (This again is my personal opinion)

I have favorited around 90 question till date and it gets very very very difficult if I want to search for a question which I remember I have favorited, which defeats the entire purpose of one favouriting a question, so here is my small suggestion.

### Favorites by tags

**Screen 1**

> [image]

**Screen 2**

> [image]

Please share your opinions on this.

Comment: Can't get what is your exact feature request?? And are you talking about favorite questions or tags?

Comment: Tag filter in Favourites question

Comment: While helpful, the solution from @hims056 is inadequate (as acknowledged -- 'it would be nice').  It requires intentional effort -- but I often can't even remember what I forgot.  A list of tags that each link to one's list of related Favorites would let me browse Favorites for maintenance and review.  But, I imagine filtering-by-tag presents challenges on the processing side.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It would be nice if it is implemented. But you can achieve this without this feature.
You can search for any tag from your favorite questions.

Type in the [search box](https://stackoverflow.com/search): [`[sql] infavorites:mine`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5D%20infavorites:mine)

Comment: yes, does the job. I am accepting this answer, but you know still it would be better if this feature is implemented, so that one does not have to remember the above syntax. Thanks for sharing, also is there any other such hidden tricks which you can share ?

Comment: Yeh... The hidden tricks are actually not hidden! Just go to search page and click on *Advanced Search Tips*. And the rest is yours..

Comment: cool, thanks a lot @him056