# How to quick search for specific tagged favorite questions?

Tags: discussion, bookmarks, search

I [favorited](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1776751/rubylovely?tab=favorites) lots of good questions in my SO profile. These include [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle), [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) ,[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript) etc

Now it seems too hard for me to quickly search questions related to any specific task. I need to look into each question one by one, til I find the required one.

Is there any quick way to get the all bookmarked questions related to any specific tag say [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby), so that  I don't need to look through all the other questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for `[ruby] infavorites:mine`:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby%5D+infavorites%3Amine

There is also [a feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168731/search-favorite-questions-by-tag) to simplify this.